# Can't stop foreground service stopSelf() and stopForeground(true) not working

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, vpn

I'm trying to stop my foreground service but it seems that my code not work properly

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, DNSService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

And this is my service source:

```
public class DNSService extends VpnService {
public final static String DNS_MODEL = "DNSModelIntent";

private VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
private Thread mThread;
private boolean shouldRun = true;
private DatagramChannel tunnel;
private DNSModel dnsModel;

public static final String ACTION_CONNECT       = DNSService.class.getName() + ".START";
public static final String ACTION_DISCONNECT    = DNSService.class.getName() + ".STOP";

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopSelf();
    stopForeground(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

private void setTunnel(DatagramChannel tunnel) {
    this.tunnel = tunnel;
}

private void setFileDescriptor(ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor) {
    this.fileDescriptor = fileDescriptor;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int p1, int p2) {
    mThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            dnsModel = intent.getParcelableExtra(DNS_MODEL);

            setFileDescriptor(builder.setSession(DNSService.this.getText(R.string.app_name).toString()).
                    addAddress("192.168.0.1", 24).addDnsServer(dnsModel.getFirstDns()).addDnsServer(dnsModel.getSecondDns()).establish());
            setTunnel(DatagramChannel.open());
            tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087));
            protect(tunnel.socket());
            while (shouldRun)
                Thread.sleep(100L);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileDescriptor != null) {
                try {
                    fileDescriptor.close();
                    setFileDescriptor(null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mThread.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Comment: can you call stopSelf() in other place, not in onDestroy method? like when the work that defined in onStartCommand is done.

Comment: try closing channel and thread inside onDestroy()

Comment: "it seems that my code not work properly" -- what does this mean? What are your actual symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close all running processes inside `onDestroy()` for your work to stop. The reason is that started thread is running on other process. So after you kill your service thread is still running.